# Performance indices for unequal datasets in R

Tags: r

I wanted to do the performance indices in R. My data looks like this (example):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUU2B.png)

I want to ignore the comparison of values in Time 2 and 4 in data frame 1 and then compare it with the available set of observed data. I know how to develop the equation for the performance indicators (R2, RMSE, IA, etc.), but I am not sure how to ignore the data in the simulated data frame when corresponding observed data is not available for comparison.

Comment: You can use ```df[seq(1,5,2), ]``` To ignore the rows you don't want

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. If the dataset is large it's best to use the answer suggested by @langtang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps just do a left join, and compare the columns directly?

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(d2,d1 %>% rename(simData=Data), by="Time")
```

Output:

```
   Time  Data simData
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1    57      52
2     3    88      78
3     5    19      23
```

Input:

```
d1 = structure(list(Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Data = c(52, 56, 78, 
56, 23)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

d2 = structure(list(Time = c(1, 3, 5), Data = c(57, 88, 19)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: This exactly solved my problem. Thank you.  left_join in dplyr is really useful.